# Getting error in React.js project

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error in all the pages of my react project and due to which i'm also not able to use my react devTool extention, which is showing this message:

> waiting for roots to load... to reload the inspector click here.

on clicking the button nothing is happening.

and on console it is showing this error message:

```
backend.js:9838 Uncaught TypeError: inst.setState.bind is not a function
        at getDataFiber (backend.js:9838)
        at enqueueMount (backend.js:9556)
        at mountFiber (backend.js:9624)
        at backend.js:9684
        at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Object.walkTree (backend.js:9682)
        at backend.js:8321
        at <anonymous>:52:32
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at Object.emit (<anonymous>:51:66)
        at setupBackend (backend.js:8396)
        at module.exports (backend.js:8342)
        at Agent.<anonymous> (backend.js:110)
        at Agent.g (backend.js:929)
        at Agent.EventEmitter.emit (backend.js:842)
        at backend.js:294
        at backend.js:7408
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at backend.js:7407
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Bridge._handleMessage (backend.js:7400)
        at listener (backend.js:86)
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

this issue is also present in this webpage but I can't find any useful solution in this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/609

Comment: Have you tried updating your devtool as suggested in the Link you mentioned.

Comment: According to the issue you linked, the problem may be related to the `react-devtools` library. Are you using that?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version of devtool, I have also tried to uninstall and reinstall it.. but the problem remains the same. @abdul

Comment: I am using "React Developer Tools" Chrome extension. @ShaneCavaliere

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake and hard to see with naked eyes. Usually, this warning appears when the structure of your `setState` is wrong, like that:

```
this.setState = {
     ...
};
```

or like that:

```
this.setState = ({
     ...
})
```

To solve use the correct structure:

```
this.setState({
..
});
```

Documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate